# How to populate labels for dataset preprocessing before LLM fine tuning?

Tags: llm, transformers, python, token

I am using [vicgalle/alpaca-gpt4](https://huggingface.co/datasets/vicgalle/alpaca-gpt4) dataset to fine tune a LLM.  I am trying to figure out how to tokenize the dataset's `output` column into `labels` within a dataset preprocessor. Please see the below Python code for what I mean.

How should I tokenize the labels and combine it with the tokenized text, in a dataset preprocessor, to fine tune a LLM?

```
# Python 3.11.7, datasets==2.16.1, and transformers==4.36.2
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

dataset = load_dataset("vicgalle/alpaca-gpt4", split="train")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
MAX_LENGTH = tokenizer.model_max_length


def preprocess(x):
    tokenized_text = tokenizer(
        x["text"],
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH,
        truncation=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )
    # How do I tokenize the "output" field and combine it with tokenized_text?
    tokenized_text["labels"] = # Unsure what to put here
    return tokenized_text


prepared_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, batched=True).train_test_split(seed=42)
```

How can I tokenize the labels?